# q-select из quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar.js

Всем привет.
Вопрос по работае с q-select

Как передать в селект значение по умолчанию, если опциями селекта является массив объектов?

Можно сделать так:

```
  <q-select
     :disable="!year"
      v-model="month"
     :options="monthOptions"
      option-label="title"
      option-value="value"
      borderless
      dense
      emit-value
      map-options
      class="col qselect dense"
      style="max-width: 176px !important"
  />

 const monthList = ref([
  { title: 'Январь', value: 0 },
  { title: 'Февраль', value: 1 },
...
])

const month = ref(monthlist.value[0])
```

Да, так будет стоять нужно значение по умолчанию в селекте, но селект будет возращать объект из массива. А мне нужно в результате, только значение, а не весь объект.

Как сделать так чтобы по умолчанию в селекте был title, а возращаемое значение селекта было value, а не весь объект целиком

Answer (score 1):

Ничего страшного, что приходит объект. Принимайте объект и берите из него value.

```
 <q-select
    ...
    @update:model-value="selectSubmit"
 />


function selectSubmit(val){
  if (!val) return;
  console.log(val.value);     
}
```